# How to `docker-compose up --build` without downtime?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I change something in `docker-compose.yml`, or add a new service, I need to run `docker-compose up --build`. How can I not have downtime for services that were not changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the service you want to build/start. The other services won't be restared/rebuild, even if their configuration was changed:

`$ docker-compose up --build <service-name>`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement a load balanced setup where you have more than one instance of the same service running. Your load balancer eg nginx would have to know about the various nodes/instances and split traffic between them.

For example, `my-api` service with the same configurations duplicated as `my-api-1` and `my-api-2`. Then you would rebuild your main image and restart one service at a time.

Doing this would allow a service instance to continue to reply to traffic while the other instance(s) restart with the new image.

There are other implementation details to consider when implementing load balanced solutions (eg health checks), but this is the high level solution.